# How to pass a set of React Nodes to unrelated components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I have a question about React, here's a simplified version of a React app.

In the app I want to render a fixed primary menu and a secondary menu that is optional and its content is controlled by inner components rendered in routing.

Also secondary menu is rendered somewhere else in mobile version of the app.

```
function App() {
    return <Router>
        <PrimaryMenu/>

        <SecondaryMenu/>

        <LayoutContent/>
        {/* This block is rendered only on mobile devices */}
        <Responsive  {...Responsive.onlyMobile}>
            <SecondaryMenu/>
        </Responsive>
    </Router>;
}
```

LayoutContent will render actual page content (using a `Page` component) according to routing rules and every page component may render its own secondary menu like this (e.g. page1 has its own submenu, page2 has another one, page3 has not.)

```
<Page title='Page 1 - With secondary menu'>
    <SecondaryMenuItems>
        {/* I want this content as children of secondary menu in both mobile and desktop menubars */}
        <li>Page 1 item 1</li>
        <li>Page 1 item 2</li>
    </SecondaryMenuItems>
</Page>
```

I tried to implement it by using React Contexts but if I store children nodes in context an infinite render is triggered. I changed it to use a id property in `<SecondaryMenuItems/>` component but the approach is very fragile and also has some drawbacks.

Here's my [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/secondary-menu-example-4fc13) it's working but as I said is pretty fragile:

- What if I use a duplicate id for secondary menus?
- What if I forget a secondary menu key?

Also if you switch to a page with a menu and then go to page3 (that has no menu) previous page menu remain on screeen.

How to accomplish this with react? Is there a suggested way to do that?

A simpler way to express my question is "how to pass a set of react nodes between unrelated components (e.g. siblings components)"

#### Update

I've completed my working example with received hints, now by combining `useRef` with `ReactDOM.createPortal` I achieved final result which is now in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Portal will let you render secondary menu items from a page into secondary menu container that exists somewhere else

All you need to do is to call React.createPortal in render of thepage, pass rendered element and target node to render into, regardless of position in DOM tree

I've edited your example using portals here https://codesandbox.io/s/secondary-menu-example-vbm3x. This of course is a basic example, you might want to abstract portals logic in a separate component for convenience, and/or pass dom reference from parent, instead of calling getElementById on mount

Comment: Nice. I meant to include a section about portals in my answer but forgot. Worth nothing these are intended to be used *outside* the React-controlled section of the DOM (not sure if that is or is not what Fabio is looking for).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, only the element you portal to shouldn't be rendered to by React. Controlling elements around it is fine @Codebling

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've finally got a working example that I'm gonna post in my question

Answer (score 0):

## Rendering same children in multiple sibling nodes

The question asks "how to *pass* a set of react nodes". Ideally, don't. If you are rendering nodes somewhere in your hierarchy with the intention of using them *elsewhere*, you may be using the wrong strategy.

If you need to render the same components in different places, make a function that renders the components, and call it from both places. In other words, ***always pass the information, not the rendered elements***.

### Render inside the router

In a typical Single Page Application, the router will render all of the (non-static) components. This is how the example should have done it. The routing component (`LayoutContent`) should have been responsible for rendering the "passed nodes" (`SecondaryMenu`) directly.

```
<Route path="/page1">
  <Page title="Page 1 - With secondary menu">
    <SecondaryMenu id="menu1"> {/* <- use SecondaryMenu instead of SecondaryMenuItems */}
      <li>Page 1 item 1</li>
      <li>Page 1 item 2</li>
    </SecondaryMenu>           {/* <- use SecondaryMenu instead of SecondaryMenuItems */}
  </Page>
</Route>
```

### When rendering inside the router is impossible

If for some reason the routing component cannot render the content directly, then a Single Page Application (or routing) solution is probably the wrong solution here. The question doesn't include any information as to why the components can't be rendered inside the router, feel free to edit the question and comment with more info.

Another way of achieving the example would be for there to be no routing component (i.e. no `LayoutContent`) and for `SecondaryMenu` to check the path of the page and conditionally render the appropriate content based on that. 
It may seem silly to manually render conditionally based on a path when there is a router component which does this for you, and I would agree. The solution is then to not use a router at all. Trying to render children in the router and passing them has a strong code smell.

In the React hierarchical layout, if the same information is needed make decisions about rendering in multiple places (the path in this case), move that information up to the nearest parent of all components and pass it down as props or as context.

## Avoiding ID clashes

### "What if I use a duplicate id for secondary menus?"

If you call a function to render the secondary menu instead of rendering it and passing it, then you can pass a menu prefix in the props, and use this menu prefix in the function.

```
function SecondaryMenuItems({ children, idPrefix, path }) {
  if (path == '/path1') {
    return (
      <ul id={`${idPrefix}-newlist`}>
```

## On keys

### "What if I forget a secondary menu key?"

React keys need only be unique [within a rendered list](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings). In fact, keys are simply an optimisation to prevent React having to re-render a generated list on every pass. If you forget to include a key (or make a bad choice of key), React has to re-render the list every time, but it's not more serious than that. In simple cases, you won't notice the drop in performance.

Comment: I cannot pass info as properties, because they are used to build complex elements in menus. If I pass those I have lot of duplicates. Also I don't want to use a series of if/else if/else in the function. I'm trying to add a set of components as menu items with attached behavior.